# Extract Data from a Table in a Scanned Document - Python Tesseract

Tags: image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

I received a Claim report from a Customer in a weekly basis which is a scanned document and I would like to process it with Python in order to get the information back in an excel.

So as you can see in the Screenshot which is my image I have a table of nine columns. The problem is that with the below script sometimes is returning me back a wrong containe number (missing a char or sometimes read the 5 as S etc.) .
My first thought is that the format is always the same e.g the Actual Quantity is always like this ##,###, The Permitted Moisture ##% so is there a way to help it recognize those columns ?

Also for the Containers, i have a list with all the Containers numbers i used for this Customer so those numbers will be 100% in my list, is there a way to help it recognize the Container Number ?

Lastly how can i Combine all this info in one since i need to process hundreds of image ?

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe' 

image_path = 'myimage.png'
image = Image.open(image_path)

enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
image = enhancer.enhance(1.5)  # Increase contrast
image = image.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
image = image.convert('L')  # Convert to grayscale

config = r'--psm 6 --oem 3 preserve_interword_spaces=1'

extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', config=config)

# Split the extracted text into lines
lines = extracted_text.strip().split('\n')
lines
```

My Image:

[image]